# Questions about Citymaps

Tags: android-studio, citymaps

1、I want to create a circle and set an image that customized to fill the circle，use this as a marker on the map, not only could change the image but also the color of circle anytime，what can I do to implements this function? Please look at the picture below!
[image: an customized marker on the map]

2、Like your CityMaps app show，when I enlarge the map, some business icon that hide are show on the map，which are hide again while shrink the map, How to achieve this effect？

3、After I initialization the Object Marker and called the method marker.setFadeTime(3000)，the software give my tips the method is no exist and I see the class Marker.java but really not find the method，Why is it so？

4、I want to add some stars beside the marker like this:
[image: the star level beside the marker]

What can I do to add the stars？the label only can set the text beside the marker.

5、I want to load your maps at the fragment，not the activity that extends FragmentActivity，I found the SupportCitymapsMapFragment is no use，What I can do to complete this requirement?

6、In your apps，it is locate that place after input New York in the search box，What can i do to complete this function whatever i input？

7、During I develop the apps about the Citymaps，I found a serious problem so that your apps had happend too. When I run the apps， the program force flash back all of a sudden and I run your apps Citymaps at this time，the problems are same of the front，I found some error  in logical view that is follows：15327-15374/com.map.maplbs A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 15374 (Thread-1819).
     To solve the problem，I must restart my device. Why is it so？

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer on the Citymaps SDK, I will do my best to answer your questions.

1) I recommend using the Android `Canvas` API to construct the images, and then use a `Marker` to display it on the map.  See the documentation for details: http://developer.citymaps.com/markers

2) This is built into the Citymaps `BusinessLayer`.  This functionality is not exposed through an API.  If you wish to use the Citymaps `BusinessLayer`, you should create a `CitymapsMapView` or `CitymapsMapFragment`/`SupportCitymapsMapFragment` and it will automatically be added to your map.

3) At this time, there appears to be a known issue with the `fadeTime` API.  Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  We will fix it in an upcoming release.  For now, you can animate the `alpha` property of the `Marker`.

4) Once again, the functionality of the `BusinessLayer` is not directly exposed.  If you wish to create similar markers, I recommend you construct the image using Android's `Canvas` and then adding it as a `Marker` to the map.

5) If you wish to load the map inside of a fragment, you can accomplish this using child fragments (check Android documentation for more details).  You can also accomplish this by instantiating `CitymapsMapView` or `MapView` directly and adding it to your view hierarchy either in XML or in code.  However if you do this, remember to call the lifecycle methods on your map instance, or else the map will not behave properly.

6) If you wish to have a search in your app, it is up to you to implement this feature. We do not currently provide a search API out of the box.

7) Thank you for the bug report.  We will investigate this issue and fix it in a future release.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask, and thank you for using the Citymaps SDK.